# UIButton Randomize Title With Single Characters

Tags: random, uibutton, character, title

The code below takes a string, adds each letter to an array and shuffles that array and shows the end result in a label. That works well. But I'd like for each character to contain a single character of the shuffled string. Right now it almost works, but it always repeats the characters. Like instead of having a series of 6 buttons with their titles: **L e a g u e,** the code generates repeated characters like: **Leaauu.**

My code is this:

```
- (IBAction)shuffleButttonTitles:(id)sender {

    // The mutable array must be created here to create a new instance each time the button is tapped
    letters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    str = @"League";

    length = str.length;

    NSString *letter;

    UIButton *button;

    // First loop through the string and add each letter to an array
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [str characterAtIndex:i]];
        [letters addObject:letter];

    }

    // Shuffle the string for the label/buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        int value = arc4random() % (length - 1);
        [letters exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:value];

        //Create the button and shuffle the letters for their titles
        button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50 * i, 350, 44, 44)];

        // HERE THE CODE REPEATS THE CHARACTERS
        [button setTitle:[letters objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //Store the button in our array
        [myButtons addObject:button];
        NSLog(@"Letters in Array: %lu", letters.count);
    }

    for (UIButton *button in myButtons){

        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:button];


    }

    // Now we set the randomized title to the label 
    NSString *results = [letters componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    string.text = results;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching on the web I've figured it out. I post the complete code for others. This code takes a random string from the Characters.txt file and shuffles that string. Then it rotates the tiles slighty. You can enter the correct word when you have figured out the anagram, which then shows an alert view if you got it or didn't get it.

```
#define kTileSpacing 20
#define randomf(minX,maxX) ((float)(arc4random() % (maxX - minX + 1)) + (float)minX)

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{

}

@synthesize progressView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Anagrams" ofType:@"plist"];
    dictionary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSString *quotesFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Characters" ofType:@"txt"];
    fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:quotesFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    // [txtField becomeFirstResponder];
    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkWord:) name:nil object:nil];
}

- (IBAction)clear:(id)sender {

    quoteArray = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSString *quoteToDisplay;

    currentQuestion = arc4random() % quoteArray.count;
    quoteToDisplay = [quoteArray objectAtIndex: currentQuestion];
    welldone.text = quoteToDisplay;

    txtField.text = nil;
    [txtField becomeFirstResponder];

    for (UILabel *lbl in myButtons) {

        [lbl removeFromSuperview];

    }
}

- (IBAction)ShuffleString:(id)sender {

    [self clear:nil];

    // The mutable array must be created here to create a new instance each time the button is tapped
    charactersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    indexArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    myButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // 1. Shuffle the plist with the words to form anagrams from
    currentQuestion = arc4random() % quoteArray.count;
    str = [quoteArray objectAtIndex: currentQuestion]; //[[dictionary objectAtIndex:currentQuestion] objectForKey:@"Anagram"];
    length = str.length;

    NSString *letter;

    // 2. Loop throught the chosen word and break it down into its letters and add them to an array
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

//        [charactersArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [str characterAtIndex:i]];
        [charactersArray addObject:letter];
       // NSLog(@"Number of letters: %@", charactersArray);

    }

    while ([charactersArray count]) {

        int randomizing = arc4random() % [charactersArray count];
        [indexArray addObject:[charactersArray objectAtIndex:randomizing]];
        [charactersArray removeObjectAtIndex:randomizing];
      //  NSLog(@"NO REPEAT SHUFFLE: %lu", (unsigned long)indexArray.count);

    }


    /***************/
    CGFloat staticY = self.view.bounds.size.height / 9 * 1; // Static X for all buttons.
    CGFloat staticWidth = 46; // Static Width for all Buttons.
    CGFloat staticHeight = 46; // Static Height for all buttons.

    CGFloat staticPadding = 10; // Padding to add between each button.
    float tileSize = ceilf( self.view.bounds.size.width / str.length );
    NSLog(@"size %f", tileSize);
    CGFloat xOffset = (self.view.bounds.size.width - str.length * (44+staticPadding));
    NSLog(@"xOffset %f", tileSize);
    xOffset = tileSize/ 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        singleCharacterLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        singleCharacterLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        singleCharacterLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:21];

        singleCharacterLabel.frame = CGRectMake((staticPadding + (i * (staticHeight + staticPadding))), staticY, staticWidth, staticHeight);
       // NSLog(@"X: %f", (staticPadding + (i * (staticHeight + staticPadding))));
        //singleCharacterLabel.center = CGPointMake(i * 50 + self.view.bounds.origin.x + self.view.bounds.size.width /3, 80); // i * int +self... int = space between labels. Here it is '50'
    //    singleCharacterLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * i, self.view.bounds.size.height / 5 * 1); // 1/4th down from the top
        singleCharacterLabel.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tile.png"]].CGColor;

        NSString *anagramString = [indexArray objectAtIndex:i];
        singleCharacterLabel.text = anagramString;
        [myButtons addObject:singleCharacterLabel];

        //1
        //set random rotation of the tile
        //anywhere between -0.2 and 0.3 radians
        float rotation = randomf(0,50) / (float)100 - 0.2;
        singleCharacterLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( rotation );

        //2
        //move randomly upwards
        int yOffset = (arc4random() % 10) - 10;
        singleCharacterLabel.center = CGPointMake(singleCharacterLabel.center.x, singleCharacterLabel.center.y + yOffset);


        [self.view addSubview:singleCharacterLabel];
        //NSLog(@"LOOP: %@", anagramString);

    }


}

- (IBAction)checkWord:(id)sender {

    if (([txtField.text  isEqual:str])) {
        alertCorrect = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Well done!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Next", nil];
        [alertCorrect show];
    } else {
        alertWrong = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Sorry, try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertWrong show];

    }

    //   NSLog(@"String is: %lu", str.length);

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (alertView == alertCorrect) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            [self ShuffleString:nil];
            NSLog(@"next");
        }
    }

    if (alertView == alertWrong) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            // Wrong answer. Close view and let user try again
        }

    }

}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (txtField.text.length == length) {
        [self checkWord:nil];
        NSLog(@"You entered %lu characters", length);
    }

    return YES;
}
```